# Custom clientside validation for required at least one in array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following custom attribute that is used to validate if an array has had a value submitted:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RequiredArrayAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public RequiredArrayAttribute()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = (IList)value;

        if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        string errorMessage = this.ErrorMessage;

        // Get the specific error message if set, otherwise the default
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) && metadata != null)
        {
            errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        }

        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
            ValidationType = "requiredarray"
        };

        return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

Applied to

```
[RequiredArray(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one product")]
public IEnumerable<string> ProductIds { get; set; }
```

And the following js (included after jquery.js, unobtrusive-ajax.js, validate.js and validate.unobtrusive.js)

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('requiredarray', function (value, element, params) {
        var selector = 'input[name=' + $(element).attr('name') + ']:checked';
        return $(selector).length > 0;
    }, 'Clientside Should Not Postback');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('requiredarray');
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried changing the `addMethod` to just `return false;` but this still does nothing (and no errors in my console)

I was wondering if anyone could spot anything I had done wrong with the above code.  I have done a similar thing with an address attribute and it works just fine but for some reason I can't get this one to work?

Further to this the server side validation works.

Razor code for validation message

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductIds)
```

Example html for rendered checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ProductIds" value="EXAMPLEID1234" id="checkbox-1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="ProductIds" value="EXAMPLEID1235" id="checkbox-2" checked="checked" />
```

**EDIT**

further to this I can now get the clientside validation to work using the following

```
$.validator.addClassRules('required-group', { 'requiredarray': true });
```

instead of the `validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool` method in the above. I have also added the class `required-group` to the checkbox

However, if I use this it doesn't add the proper MVC Error message, just the `Clientside Should Not Postback` as set in the above code.  I have tried adding the following attributes to the checkbox:

```
 data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select at least one sample"
```

and also tried using `data-val-requiredarray` but this makes no difference so does anyone know how to change the above clientside rules to make it use the MVC error message

Comment: Show the _rendered_ code for everything relevant.  Where is the rendered `.validate()` method?  Where is the rendered HTML for the whole form?

Comment: @Sparky MVC handles all the validate stuff so there is no code for that as for the full form, it's just a lot of the same checkboxes with a submit button at the end

Comment: I realize that.  However, jQuery Validate is still JavaScript and it can not run without being initialized first.  The initialization method is `.validate()`.  So there MUST be the `.validate()` method rendered client-side someplace... perhaps in an included js file.

Comment: This is likely not the answer.  However, ***why*** are you constructing a selector within your custom method?  What do you think the `element` argument represents?  It is the selector itself.  It's unnecessarily circular to take the given element, find its name, then use that name to find the element you already had in the first place.

Comment: That selector should get me all checkboxes with that name that are checked. I thought element was only the current element been checked / unchecked

Comment: `element` **is** the current element being validated; and so `$(element).attr('name')` is the `name` of the _current element_ being validated.  So again, how is `$('input[name=' + $(element).attr('name') + ']')` any different than `$(element)`?  Think about it:  You are taking the current `element`, finding its `name`, then using that `name` to find the same `element` you already had in the first place.  You're going in a circle to get something you already have.

Comment: See:  http://jsfiddle.net/g3uZ2/

Comment: @Sparky this is how it is different http://jsfiddle.net/g3uZ2/2/, I have multiple checkboxes with the same name, as stated in my previous comment I need all checboxes, not just the current one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was fixed with the following changes to the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox required-group" name="ProductIds" value="EXAMPLEID1234" id="checkbox-1" checked="checked" data-val-required="Please select at least one sample" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox required-group" name="ProductIds" value="EXAMPLEID1235" id="checkbox-2" checked="checked" />
```

`data-val-required` only needs to be on the first checkbox in the array.  Then using the following jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('requiredarray', function (value, element, params) {
        return $('input[name=' + $(element).attr('name') + ']:checked').length > 0;
    }, 'Please select at least one');

    $.validator.addClassRules('required-group', { 'requiredarray': true });

    var errorMessage = $('.required-group').eq(0).data('val-requiredarray');
    if (errorMessage && errorMessage !== "") {
        $.validator.messages.requiredarray = errorMessage;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I have changed the `addBool` to `addClassRules` and then used `$.validator.messages` to set the error message.